# likelihood of major earthquake each year when only 30 year probability is known

Tags: probability

Everyone, in the Bay Area we hear that the likelihood of a 7.1 magnitutude earthquake on our local Hayward Fault that would cause liquefaction is 31% sometime in the next 30 years.

What I'd like to understand is how you calculate the probability of that magnitude earthquake EVERY year of that 30 year time span. And does it increase every year that the event does not occur?

Comment: Have you heard of Poisson distribution?

Comment: Over a period of time as short as 30 years, you could probably use a Poisson approximation and not be too far off.  However, it's probably also true that if it doesn't happen for long enough, the rate at which it happens (essentially, the probability that it happens in the next year) starts going up.

Comment: The USGS publish quite a lot of information on where the forecasts come from, see for example [here](https://pubs.usgs.gov/fs/2008/3027/fs2008-3027.pdf) without knowing a bit more about it I suspect a 30 year forecast is already a "convenient for humans" aggregation and not easily reverse engineered to answer something like "if no earthquake this year, then  more likely next year?"

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the likelihood of such a quake happening in the span of a year is $x$, and assuming independence between the year, then the likelihood of it never happening in the next 30 years is $(1-x)^{30}$, and hence the probability of it happening at least once is $1-(1-x)^{30}$  So, solve for:

$$1-(1-x)^{30} = 0.31$$

Comment: I'm not sure the assumption of independence sounds geologically plausible -- though, of course, without it it's rather impossible to get any computation going.

Answer (score 0):

Another reasonable sounding assumption is that large earthquakes are anticorrelated in time because the fact that one happens will relieve the stress and prevent another one from happening soon.  If 30 years qualifies as soon you can't have more than one earthquake in the span and you can just say it is $\frac {31}{30}\%\approx 1.03\%$ per year for that span.  I don't claim this is a better model than independence, which gives about $1.23\%$ per year.  This gives an idea of how the assumptions can change the result.